# Show $f(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$ is global Lipchitz

Tags: real-analysis

> Show $f(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$ is global Lipchitz

---

Let $x,y\in[0,\infty)$ such that

$\begin{align*}\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|&=\left|\frac{x}{x+1}-\frac{y}{y+1}\right|\\&=\left|\frac{x-y}{(x+1)(y+1)}\right|\\&\leq \left|\frac{x-y}{(x+1)(y+1)}\right|\leq\left|\frac{x-y}{(x+1)(y+1)} (x+1)(y+1)\right|=\left|x-y\right|\end{align*}$

Thus $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 1\times|x-y|$.

---

Does this enough to show $f(x)$ is global Lipchitz? Thanks

Comment: Are you given the domain is $[0,\infty )$? Not stated in the question.  If so,  looks good.   If not,  there's a problem at the multipying by (x+1)(y+1) step

Comment: @Alan, yes, it is on $[0,\infty)$

Comment: Then yes,  everything's good, it's Liptschitz with constant (at most) 1 (and probably at least too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. The proof can be simplified as:

Since $x\geqslant0,y\geqslant0$, $\frac1{x+1}\leqslant1,\frac1{y+1}\leqslant1$. Thus
$$
\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|=\left|\frac{x-y}{(x+1)(y+1)}\right|\leqslant |x-y|
$$